# PlayOnLinux console not opening

Tags: command-line, xubuntu, 64-bit, playonlinux, console

When I click the entry for the PlayOnLinux console, under the Tools menu, I only see a brief flicker in a part of my screen and the console fails to load. it loads fine when I run `playonlinux-shell` in the terminal. I am using the zsh 5.1.1 shell with oh-my-zsh and PlayOnLinux 4.2.12 on Xubuntu 16.04 64-bit.

Any idea why this is happening and how to fix it?

Comment: Remove all of PlayOnLinux and install the `wine` command that is a great alternative to install and run any Windows app, here is my explanation : https://askubuntu.com/questions/1437380/ubuntu-22-04-how-to-run-an-exe-file-by-the-desktop-shortcut